# Should I use which or what?

Tags: which-what

If I am referring to the alternatives of a quiz (with a limited number of options) and I want to ask someone the correct alternative, should I say:

> What is the correct alternative?

Or

> Which is the correct alternative?

Answer (score 2):

"Which" is preferred in the scenario of a limited number of options. So in your case, as you are presenting a quiz, where participants would pick one between multiple options,

> Which (one) is the correct alternative/ answer/ option?

would be the most appropriate.